# ICEfaces SelectOneMenu ValueChangeListener not working

Tags: jsf, icefaces-1.8

I have a simple `ice:SelectOneMenu` and an `ice:outputLabel` and all I want to do is when I change the value in my dropdown to set the text in my label to tell me that I changed the value and what the new value is (simple test, once this works I will actually update an `ice:dataTable` with this)

I have been working at this for a couple days now. [This link](http://java-server-faces.blogspot.com/2006/04/valuechangelisteners-what-you-need-to.html) gave me some good info on phases and events, and I've tried all of the solutions but none seem to work for me. This is a very non-trivial task in asp.net, and I don't understand why it is so complicated in jsf. I guess I should mention that I also have an `ice:selectInputDate` on the page and when I click the icon to open the calendar for date selection, my SOM valuechangelistener is either finally called or it finally renders the new label text (I'm guessing the latter). Can anyone help me to get this working? I really appreciate the help, thanks.

```
<ice:selectOneMenu valueChangeListener="#{easp$PartsInv.changeRC}"  binding="#{easp$PartsInv.SOM_RC}" id="SOM_RC">
    <f:selectItems binding="#{easp$PartsInv.SOM_RC_Items}" id="SOM_RC_Items" />
</ice:selectOneMenu>

<ice:outputLabel binding="#{easp$PartsInv.lblStatus}" id="lblStatus" style="color:red;" value=""></ice:outputLabel>
```

Current java code (changed several times trying different things):

```
//event raised when user chooses a new RC (Repair Center) value.
public void changeRC(ValueChangeEvent vce)
{
    String oldVal = vce.getOldValue().toString();

    if(oldVal != null){
        String newVal = vce.getNewValue().toString();
        this.lblStatus.setValue("RC changed to " + newVal);
        if(!newVal.equals(oldVal)){
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As to the shout for help (which I edited away), this is on paper indeed a trivial job with JSF2/RichFaces/PrimeFaces. But unfortunately, I'm not familiar with IceFaces. I can only post generic JSF1/JSF2 targeted answers and to a certain degree also RichFaces/PrimeFaces. This question is too IceFaces specific.

Comment: Hehe yeah, i just knew that no one else would post on this, since you are the only response i've gotten on my last 4 jsf posts and i was kinda being a smartass. Anyway, I wonder if your JSF targeted answers would be of any help, definitely worth a shot :)

Comment: In JSF 1.x it's complicated because it doesn't natively support ajax requests (or partial requests, as IceFaces calls it itself). In JSF 2.x it's a matter of a single `<f:ajax>` tag. RichFaces has `<a4j:ajax>` and PrimeFaces `<p:ajax>`. I *believe* IceFaces achieves the same effect by setting `partialSubmit="true"` attribute (I am not aware of any tag). But you should somewhere put an action listener on it, definitely not a value change listener as it's invoked *before* model values are updated (which may overridde any changes made in value change listener).

Comment: Wow.. partialSubmit="true" did the trick. Thx man. I can't believe that was it >< I thought I had tried that..thx again. post answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `partialSubmit="true"` to the component, exactly as demonstrated somewhere near the bottom of their [component reference](http://www.icefaces.org/docs/v1_8_2/htmlguide/devguide/references7.html).